# Disabeling of the translation selector

Tags: modeling

Is one able to disable the display of the axis translation selector? I'm specifically talking about this: [image].

I try to learn how to use blender, but i'm not able to properly follow my backround image because i constantly hit it when i try to add a point. It's really annoying because i have to add the point elsewhere and then translate it to the place it should have gone in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're adding vertices by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking.

[image]

This button, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> toggles the visibility of the manipulator.

Using one of the shortcuts - (<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>) for translation, rotation, or scale, dismisses the manipulator, even if it was visible.

In an orthogonal view, using <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, (rather than place,) new vertices, allows you to move them about in screen space, without having to go to a separate operation.